# subassignment of selected layers in raster brick

Tags: r, r-raster

I want to modify a subset of layers in a raster brick by multiplying those layers by another raster.

For example, if we have a raster brick called 'r.brick' and we try to multiply its layers 2:4 by a raster, 'r.mult', with same row&column dimensions:

- `r.brick[[2:4]]` returns layers 2:4, as expected
- `r.brick[[2:4]] * r.mult` successfully multiplies those layers, as expected

but, if I try to assign the result back into the subset layers I get an error

```
r.brick[[2:4]] = r.brick[[2:4]] * r.mult
# Error in value[] <- val : 
#   incompatible types (from S4 to double) in subassignment type fix
```

The error message suggests that the assignment is trying to assign the raster *values* rather than the raster itself.  But if I try the assignment with `getValues`, I get a different error:

```
r.brick[[2:4]] = getValues(r.brick[[2:4]] * r.mult)
# Error in .local(x, values, ...) : length(values) is not equal to ncell(x)
```

What is the correct way to do this?

**Some reproducible data:**

```
library(raster)
r.list = vector("list", 20)
set.seed(123)
for (i in 1:20) {
  r.list[[i]] = raster(vals=runif(100), nrows=10, ncols=10, ext=extent(c(0,25,0,25)))
}
r.brick = brick(r.list)
r.mult = raster(vals=sample(2,100,T), nrows=10, ncols=10, ext=extent(c(0,25,0,25)))
```

Comment: Did you try using setValues ? (Don't know if it allows to assign on multiple layers, though...)

Comment: @LorenzoBusetto setValues only seems to work on single layers, so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is a missing feature. Thanks for pointing that out. I would go with the loop following maRtin (perhaps after creating a RasterStack, that may be more efficient). If the dataset is not too large, you can do

```
# example data
library(raster)
b <- brick(nrows=2, ncols=2, nl=6)
values(b) <- rep(1:4, 6) 
r.mult <- raster(vals=10, nrows=2, ncols=2)


values(b)[,3:4] <- values(b[[3:4]] * r.mult)
# values(b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Then I only got a workaround (using a loop) for you:

```
layers <- 2:4
for(i in layers) {
  r.brick[[i]]  <- r.brick[[i]] * r.mult
}
```

*Note:* Apparently the assignment with the `[]` subsetting only works with single layers.

Comment: Right. Didn't test it since I was on the road. I got a another workaround for you. Maybe @RobertH can help you better. :)

Comment: Thanks - I'm already using a loop workaround - was hoping there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following code with multiple layers 2-4 of r.brick raster values with r.mult values and assign the results to r.brick layers 2-4.

```
attr(attr(r.brick, 'data'), 'values')[,2:4] = attr(attr(r.brick, 'data'), 'values')[,2:4] * attr(attr(r.mult, 'data'), 'values')
```

or

```
attr(attr(r.brick, 'data'), 'values')[,2:4] = getValues(r.brick[[2:4]] * r.mult)
```

Comment: That is not a good solution. It will only work on some cases (small data sets) and os needlessly obscure.