# Efficient way to interpolate time series of raster bricks in R

Tags: r, raster, zoo

I have some large raster bricks that represent time series (each layer is one time point). I wish to increase the time resolution by interpolating between layers (in the example below interpolation is using `zoo::na.spline`, although I am open to other interpolation methods if they help). I can't use `na.spline` directly on the bricks - it's not designed for that and just gives `Error in as.array.default(X) : 'dimnames' applied to non-array`.

At the moment I am using a series of loops to do this (1 loop to generate a brick with more time layers, a 2nd loop to insert the original brick into the correct layers of this, and a 3rd loop to use na.spline on each cell). However, this is horribly slow on large bricks and seems to be a rather inefficent approach.

**A minimal reproducible example.**

First lets make an intial raster brick representing the low time resolution data. Note that the top left cell is always NA, as any solution must be robust for cells that only contain NA:

```
library(raster); library(rasterVis); library(zoo)
r1 = raster(matrix(c(NA, rep(1,8)), 3, 3))
r2 = raster(matrix(c(NA, rep(2,8)), 3, 3))
r3 = raster(matrix(c(NA, rep(3,8)), 3, 3))    
b1 = brick(list(r1,r2,r3))
levelplot(b1)
```

[image]

Now, lets create an empty raster brick in which to insert the values:

```
b2 = brick(lapply(1:9, function(x) raster(matrix(NA, 3, 3))))
```

Next we insert the layers of `b1` into the appropriate layers of `b2`. Note that I even resort to a loop here because [subassignment of selected layers into raster bricks does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639976/subassignment-of-selected-layers-in-raster-brick).

```
old.layers = c(1,4,7)
for (i in 1:nlayers(b1)) {
  b2[[old.layers[i]]] = b1[[i]]
} 
levelplot(b2, layout=c(9,1))
```

[image]

Finally we loop over each cell to do the time series interpolation and insert the results back into `b2`:

```
for (cell in 1:ncell(b2)) {
  if (all(is.na(as.vector(b2[cell])))) {
    # na.spline wil fail if all are NA
    new.values = as.numeric(rep(NA, dim(b2)[3])) 
  } else {
    new.values = na.spline(as.vector(b2[cell]), na.rm = F) 
  }
  b2[cell][] = new.values
}
levelplot(b2, layout=c(9,1))
```

[image]

This works but seems to be extremely inefficient and inelegant. Is there a faster (and preferably also more elegant) way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `raster::calc` with a function like this:

```
yy <- rep(NA, 9)
fun <- function(y) { 
  if (all(is.na(y)))  yy else na.spline((yy[c(1,4,7)] <- y), xout=1:9)
}
b2 <- calc(b1,  fun)
```

For reference, `raster::approxNA` comes close to what you want (but it does not add layers, and uses linear interpolation).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a neat solution, but I can't get it to work. I just get a single raster layer with all values equal to 1.  NB I assume it should be `b2 <- calc(b1,  fun)`.  I see in ?calc that "returns a RasterBrick if fun returns more than one number, " but for some reason I'm not getting this behaviour

Comment: I've changed the code slightly to deal with NA's more robustly.  The original version seemed to be thrown by these (hence issue noted in comment above).  Thanks again - I was not aware that `calc` could return a brick rather than a single layer, so this is a very useful learning exercise.